# Javascript HTML button click to add marker to map

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Im using Google map API V3 with drawing manager to add and save markers to the map. It works fine with the default drawing manager tools. I have the drawingMode set to null so it is inactive until the marker button is clicked - this works with the default set up.

I now have my own custom HTML button that when clicked it activates the drawing manager MARKER tool:

```
<button id="add-event-button" type="button" class="btn btn-success"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus-sign"></span> Add Event</button>
```

My Javascript is:

```
document.getElementById('add-event-button').onclick = function()
{
    drawingMode: google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.MARKER;
}
```

But when it is clicked it does nothing, and returns 0 errors. I replaced

```
drawingMode: google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.MARKER;
```

with

```
alert("button was clicked ");
```

to see if it is reading the button click and it worked. So what should be added to activate the MARKER tool??

Answer (score 2):

This works for me (and doesn't require jquery):

```
document.getElementById('add-event-button').onclick = function() {
  drawingManager.setDrawingMode(google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.MARKER);
}
```

Working code snippet:

```js
function initialize() {
  var mapOptions = {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644),
    zoom: 8
  };

  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
    mapOptions);

  var drawingManager = new google.maps.drawing.DrawingManager({
    drawingMode: google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.MARKER,
    drawingControl: true,
    drawingControlOptions: {
      position: google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_CENTER,
      drawingModes: [
        google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.MARKER,
        google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.CIRCLE,
        google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.POLYGON,
        google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.POLYLINE,
        google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.RECTANGLE
      ]
    },
    markerOptions: {
      icon: 'http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/blue.png'
    },
    circleOptions: {
      fillColor: '#ffff00',
      fillOpacity: 1,
      strokeWeight: 5,
      clickable: false,
      editable: true,
      zIndex: 1
    }
  });
  drawingManager.setMap(map);
  document.getElementById('add-event-button').onclick = function() {
    drawingManager.setDrawingMode(google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.MARKER);
  }
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

```css
html, body, #map-canvas {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px
      }
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=drawing"></script>
<button id="add-event-button" type="button" class="btn btn-success"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus-sign"></span> Add Event</button>
<div id="map-canvas"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to do it via the drawingManager setOptions method, e.g.:

```js
drawingManager.setOptions({
  drawingControlOptions: {
    drawingModes: [google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.MARKER]
  }
});
```

So in your case:

```js
document.getElementById('add-event-button').onclick = function()
{
        drawingManager.setOptions({
            drawingControlOptions: {
                drawingModes: [google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.MARKER]
            }
        });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#add-event-button").click( function(){
    drawingManager.setDrawingMode(google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.MARKER);
});
```